# Function Parameters in an AST?

Tags: abstract-syntax-tree, compiler-construction

Im writing a Complier, and currently im trying to sketch out ASTs of my example codes that I know how it works. What confuses me though, is, how exactly I would represent it. I looked online for JavaScript ASTs, but they didn't have any Parameter declarations in a function declaration, which confused me. So how exactly do I draw an AST for a function with two parameters? Do I put them in the function declaration at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no experience with compiler design, but my job leads me to stare at a lot of ASTs. Here are a few examples of the specific topic you mentioned — parameters in a function declaration.

JavaScript (via [esprima](http://esprima.org/demo/parse.html)) includes function parameters as a property of the function declaration node. An example declaration of `myFunction` with arguments `argOne` and `argTwo` is below:

```
{
  "type": "FunctionDeclaration",
  "id": {
    "type": "Identifier",
    "name": "myFunction"
  },
  "params": [
    {
      "type": "Identifier",
      "name": "argOne"
    },
    {
      "type": "Identifier",
      "name": "argTwo"
    }
  ],
  "body": { ... }
}
```

As another example, consider the golang type for a [FuncDecl](https://golang.org/pkg/go/ast/#FuncDecl).

```
type FuncDecl struct {
    Doc  *CommentGroup // associated documentation; or nil
    Recv *FieldList    // receiver (methods); or nil (functions)
    Name *Ident        // function/method name
    Type *FuncType     // function signature: parameters, results, and position of "func" keyword
    Body *BlockStmt    // function body; or nil for external (non-Go) function
}
```

Function parameters are kept under the `Type` key, whose type includes a `Params` list:

```
type FuncType struct {
    Func    token.Pos  // position of "func" keyword (token.NoPos if there is no "func")
    Params  *FieldList // (incoming) parameters; non-nil
    Results *FieldList // (outgoing) results; or nil
}
```

As a final example, for variety, consider the quoted form of an Elixir function with two parameters.

```
{:def, [context: Elixir, import: Kernel],
  [
    {:myFunction, [context: Elixir],
     [{:argOne, [], Elixir}, {:argTwo, [], Elixir}]},
    [
      do: ...
    ]
  ]}
```

Here, the third element of a tuple is the "argument list," whether that's the list of arguments accepted by a function (as above) or the arguments applied to a function call.

Good luck in your compiler adventures!